# Javascript checking whether string is in either of two arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm pulling my hair out over this one. I have two arrays, `likes` & `dislikes`, both filled with about 50 strings each.

I also have a JSON object, `data.results`, which contains about 50 objects, each with an `_id` parameter.

I'm trying to check find all the objects within `data.results` that **aren't** in both `likes` and `dislikes`.

Here's my code at present:

```
var newResults = []
      for(var i = 0; i<data.results.length; i++){
        for(var x = 0; x<likes.length; x++){
          if(!(data.results[i]._id == likes[x])){
            for(var y = 0; y<dislikes.length; y++){
                if(!(data.results[i]._id == dislikes[y])){
                  newResults.push(data.results[i]);
                  console.log("pushed " + data.results[i]._id);
                }
                else
                {
                   console.log("They already HATE " + data.results[i]._id + " foo!"); //temp
                }
            }
          }
          else
          {
             console.log(data.results[i]._id + " is already liked!"); //temp
          }
        }
      }
```

As you can see, I'm iterating through all the `data.results` objects. Then I check whether their `_id` is in `likes`. If it isn't, I check whether it's in `dislikes`. Then if it still isn't, I push it to `newResults`.

As you might expect by looking at it, this code currently pushes the result into my array once for each iteration, so i end up with a massive array of like 600 objects.

What's the good, simple way to achieve this?

Comment: @rps:  This is probably *[not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)*.

Comment: @ScottSauyet thanks , never thought about the `Array.prototype.foo = 1;` but I have always used it so far without problems, Guess I better stop now.

Comment: @rps btw, using an `for ... in` loop to iterate over an array, is not only a bad idea, but also, way slower than using a standard `for` loop

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 because it checks whether any value is there or not at each index and returns value alone?

Comment: Enumerating the properties of an object includes enumerating properties of its prototype, and the prototype of the prototype, and so on, recursively; (http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4)

In other words, it has to look up the prototype chain of the array, before iterating, which is not the case in a normal for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    isInLiked = (likes.indexOf(data.results[i]) > -1);
    isInHated = (dislikes.indexOf(data.results[i]) > -1);
    if (!isInLiked && !isInHated) {
        etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, though, that if you have to support IE < 9, you will probably need a *[shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility)*.  Or you could write a simpler *[contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)* function.

Comment: @AndréDion They aren't the same length.

Answer (score 1):

When checking whether an Array contains an element, [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (*which is ECMAScript 5, but [shimmable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) for older browsers*), comes in handy. 
Even more when combined with the bitwise NOT operator `~` and a cast to a Boolean `!`

Lets take a look how this could work.

`Array.prototype.indexOf` returns -1 if an Element is not found.

Applying a `~` to -1 gives us `0`, applying an `!` to a `0` gives us `true`.

So `!~[...].indexOf (var)` gives us a Boolean represantation, of whether an Element is NOT in an Array. The other way round `!!~[...].indexOf (var)` would yield true if an Element was found.

Let's wrap this logic in a contains function, to simply reuse it.

```
function contains (array,element) {
    return !!~array.indexOf (element);
}
```

Now we only need an logical AND `&&` to combine the output, of your 2 arrays, passed to the contains function.

```
var likes = ["a","b","f"] //your likes
var dislikes = ["c","g","h"] //your dislikes

var result = ["a","c","d","e","f"]; //the result containing the strings
var newresult = []; //the new result you want the strings which are NOT in likes or dislikes, being pushed to

for (var i = 0,j;j=result[i++];) //iterate over the results array
     if (!contains(likes,j) && !contains (dislikes,j)) //check if it is NOT in likes AND NOT in dislikes
           newresult.push (j) //if so, push it to the newresult array.

console.log (newresult) // ["d","e"]
```

Here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxzGU/1)**

<sub>Edit notes:

1. Added an contains function, as @Scott suggested</sub>

Comment: I might add a `contains` function for readability: `var contains = function(haystack, needle) {return !!~haystack.indexOf(needle);};` and change the test to `if (!contains(likes, j) && !contains(dislikes, j))`.  I think that would make the code cleaner, and `contains` is clearly reusable.

Comment: @Scott yep, that sounds like a good idea =), updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use likes.indexOf(data.results[i]._id) and dislikes.indexOf(data.results[i]._id).

```
if (likes.indexOf(data.results[i]._id) != -1)
{
// they like it :D
}
```

Comment: Beware that [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) isn't supported by all browsers.

Comment: Right, forgot about old browsers :( here is the implementation for those old browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FindexOf#Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Try first creating an array of common strings between `likes` and `dislikes`

```
var commonStrAry=[];
for(var i = 0; i<likes.length; i++){
for(var j=0; j<dislikes.length; j++){
    if(likes[i] === dislikes[j]){
        commonStrAry.push(likes[i] );
    }
}
}
```

then you can use this to check against data.results and just remove the elements that don't match.